# How to use bower for Github Blog

Tags: git, github, bower

I don't know whether it's valid questions or not. I am creating a blog on [Github](http://github.com) for the first time. I am using [bower](http://bower.io/) as package manager. Here's my bower.json file.

```
{
    "name": "Code Pulses",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "authors": [
        "Hitesh Kumar"
    ],
    "license": "Copyright © 2016 Unknown :)",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "angular": "~1.4.9"
    },
    "resolutions": {
        "angular": "~1.4.9"
    }
}
```

On my local i get bower components using command `bower update --save`. When I push my change to [my repository](https://github.com/hk-skit/hk-skit.github.io), the bower_components are not getting loaded. I don't know how can I get bower components there. I don't want to push them manually. Here's the [blog](http://hk-skit.github.io/). You can see in console it says
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you pushing your `bower_component` directory to github?. If not then I think you need to push it cause github does not run `bower update --save` command when you push your changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have removed `bower` and now I am using `npm` I have renamed `node_modules` to `dev_dependencies` and it's working fine.